# Implementation of CSAFE protocol

Tags: c#, .net, protocols, .net-micro-framework

Does anyone know of an open source implementation of the CSAFE protocol? The CSAFE protocol is an open protocol specification used to interface with fitness equipment.

I'm working on an improved training computer (embedded device using .Net MF) for my Concept2 rowing machine, and not having to first implement this protocol would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Doubtful. A cursory googling and Codeplex/GitHub/Sourceforge review says no.

.NETMF is pretty new in terms of a developer base, so unless it's something common like an RTC or the interface is trivial, it's likely that you'll have to DIY.

**Edit:** looking at the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_Specification_for_Fitness_Equipment) for CSAFE, it looks like CSAFE is just garden-variety serial port connection over a different connector. If that's the case, you don't need to write a driver. However, it looks like extended mode operation enumerates on the protocol, and therefore you'd need to write a firmware driver that implements the extended behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, some one stumbles on this question, there seems to be a NodeJs package available - [node-csafe](https://github.com/mdeltito/node-csafe).